# When I press a volume up/down key, what shell command does it send?

Tags: notification, volume-control, notify-osd

I want to make a keyboard shortcut that changes the volume with exactly the same behaviour as pressing one of the default volume keys (up, down, mute), including the OSD notification and the "pop" sound. Right now, my bodged method is to have `xdotool` press the volume key, but it would be simpler to find the command the default volume keys send when pressed.

I don't want to use `unity-control-center` to reassign the volume keys, because I want to leave the default volume keys in place.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use two shortcuts , one bound to <kbd>Ctlr</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> for volume up and <kbd>Ctlr</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> for volume down, which you can set in Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom.

Shortcuts are bound to two script files, given full path (though you don't have to place the commands bellow into scripts necessarily ).

For volume up, the command in script file is:

```
amixer sset Master 10+ && notify-send "volume up 10" && sleep 0.25 && killall notify-osd
```

And for volume down the other command is

```
amixer sset Master 10- && notify-send "volume down 10" && sleep 0.25 && killall notify-osd
```

As you can guess, the two commands raise and lover volume in increments of 10 depending on your sound card. You can also use `10%+` to increase volume up 10% from what the current value is, but keep in mind that when decreasing the volume, the current value will get smaller and smaller, so it will be difficult to raise it back from smaller number (because 10% of small number will also be small)

Comment: Whoops, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I'm looking to exactly replicate the behaviour of the default volume keys, preferably using the exact command that they send. I have edited my question accordingly.